# Data Recovery Machine

Tags: cpu, motherboard, data-recovery, data-transfer, disk-cloning

When building a machine for data recovery, what specs should I look for in a CPU/MOBO?

From my understanding the BUS speed will be the most important factor over CPU speed correct? Because you are doing I/O and not really requiring CPU cycles should you run DDRecovery or some application like that.

Does memory play a big part in this as well?

I know I will want 6GBPs SATA ports.

EDIT:

Just to better explain the question.

Someone's drive fails and needs to be cloned or data pulled off of it. Or something along the lines of that. The idea is that this system would be used to plug the drives in and focus on pulling the data off and writing it to another drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data recovery:  SSDs if you can afford them and/or a RAID 5 or 6.  RAID 0 is faster but offers no safety net if 1 drive fails all the files are damaged.
At 80mb/s for hard drives it would take about 6 to equal 1 ssd with read speed.
The average SSD has 500mb/s read so 6 would be 3000mb/s.  The CPU and memory are dependent on the software.  How much info does your software cache in RAM?  As long as the CPU is around 2ghz there should be no issues.

**If you go the SSD route the faster the RAM the better. Unless you special configure your system 2000mb/s is probably the realistic MAX.  Write speeds will be slower, but will still be faster than any single hard drive by a mile.**

```
Situation 1 :  recovery to SSD
For the mobo you want something with as many 6gb/s SATA ports as you can find and the fastest memory speed.  The only thing about the CPU that matters is the bus speed to the memory and north bridge.

Situation 2 : recovery to Hard drives
hard drives are so slow it really does not matter unless your recovering a RAID.
```

If you copy the drive to be recovered to an SSD RAID and data mine that copy it will be super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking like a backup? If so what you really need to be looking for is data transfer rates (like you mentioned with the 6GB/s ports). I'd get a semi decent one but nothing to write home about. What you really want is storage size and speed. I recommend getting a $50 AMD cpu off newegg. When buying the MOBO however you want ports ports ports. Lots and lots of SATA connections. For storage I'd get an SSD big enough to hold your most recent backups and most important info. Then I'd get a bunch of very large HDD to store legacy info.